# Cannot trigger click event undefined element

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-unit-test, ng-mocks

I need to test click event on mat-table row. Below is my mat-table code

```
<table
    mat-table
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    matSort
    matSortActive="formCode"
    matSortDirection="asc"
  >
    <caption></caption>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="isChecked">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox
          (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
          (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
          [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
        >
        </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="code">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Référence</th>
      <td
        mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let element"
        class="clickable-link"
        (click)="openSummary(element.code)"
      >
        {{ element.code }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

I try to find a row by css and I do something like this:
`ngMocks.click('.clickable-link')`; or `ngMocks.click('mat-checkbox')` but it return **undefined** I already try `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-checkbox'))` but nothing changed. This my `spec.ts` file:

```
it('should open summary',async ()=>{  
     filesService.getFormByCode.and.returnValue(of(formList));
      ngMocks.click('.clickable-link');
       fixture.detectChanges();
       expect(filesService.getFormByCode).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

How can I access click event on the table's row ?

Comment: Could you show how you render `*matCellDef="let element"`? without rendering it the link isn't displayed at all. There is an example how to render mocked mat elements: https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/libraries/angular-material

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the `mat-table` before the class of `td`
what happens if you tried `ngMocks.click('table td .clickable-link');`

Answer (score 0):

When using mockbuilder, did you `.keep(MatTableModule)`?

If you don't, it's probably getting mocked, which means your table probably isn't getting rendered.